# ec2 how to add more volume to exist device

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, volume

I was trying to add more volume to my device

```
df -h
```

I get:

```
[root@ip-172-x-x-x ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        3.8G   44K  3.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1  7.8G  3.6G  4.2G  46% /
```

I wanna add all existing storage to /dev/nvme0n1p1

```
lsblk
```

I get

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1       259:0    0  300G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0    8G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p128 259:2    0    1M  0 part
```

I was trying to google around on aws instructions, still quite confuse. since most of the instruction is setting up brand new instance. While for my use case i cannot stop the instance.
i cannot do

```
mkfs
```

Also seems like the disk is already mount?? I guess i may misunderstand the meaning of mount...

since the filesystem is already there. 
just wanna use all existing space.
Thanks for help in advance!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: When you created this instance and assigned an EBS volume, how much volume did you give it? Also, you want to expand a partition, yes? What about this link? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/expand-linux-partition.html and if this doesn't answer your question? Why? It doesn't require you to stop your instance, just unmount the volume.

Answer (score 1):

your lsblk output shows that you have a 300G disk but your nvme0n1p1 is only 8G. You need to first grow your partition to fill the disk and then expand your filesystem to fill your partition:

1. Snapshot all ebs volumes you care about before doing any resize operations on them.
2. Install growpart
   `sudo yum install cloud-utils-growpart`
3. Resize partion`growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1`
4. Reboot `reboot now`
5. Run `lsblk` and verify that the partition is now the full disk size
6. You may still have to run `sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1` to expand the filesystem